# How to pass data to a field in Google forms

Tags: javascript, php, database, fetch, google-forms

**Question:** Is there any way to pass the data from my site to one field in Google Forms?

**Example:**
I have a web-page where logged `user1` is able to interact with other `user2`. At the end of interaction I want to know the opinion of the `user1` about `user2`.

I want to use Google forms for that. Creating a form with few questions and embedding it on my site is an easy one but I am trying to figure out how to create a field in "Google Form" that will fetch name of `user2` from my site/database so I `user1` does not have to type it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Google forms already have such functionality. Follow the steps to create a form and pre-fill any field and/or fields..

1. Go to Google Drive and Create New Form
2. Add all the required fields
3. Click **Responses** and select **Get pre-filled URL**
4. Fill the Values you want to be Pre-filled (*At this time the values you enter doesn't matter! You will be able to change it through URL you will get in the next step*)
5. Hit the **Submit** button! And you will be prompted with the URL
6. Just Paste the URL in the textEditor and as you can see URL has the values you entered! Just replace them with desired values or generate from the Database your choice!

And you are done! :)

For more help you can visit [this link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en)